# What is good practice: write awk inside bash script, or call bash command inside awk script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I was asigned to write a shell script to do some check on server, such as backup files, firewall status, etc. Personally, I don't like bash script's syntax, so I consider writing most of the logic in awk.

For now, I write a check.sh and wrap awk in shell functions like this:

```
check_xx(){
    shell command ...
    awk '....'
}
```

After a while, I realized that most of the time, I am doing with awk. Would it be better to write check.awk, do all the work in awk?

So my question is:

1. Is awk capable for this kind of task?
2. What is better way, put awk inside shell script, or call shell command inside awk?

Comment: Opinion questions are normally blocked. Since I am opinionated, here is my take: You can launch programs from awk, but let awk do what awk is best for, and bash what bash is best for. awk is great at text processing. bash is great at launching programs. Thus, it's normally "better" to create a shell script and run awk inside it. The awk program will be less cluttered and more to the point. However, there might be certain use cases where launching programs from awk is the logical thing to do, e.g. using awk variables as program options/parameters.